# Times font in PDF (PDFLaTeX)

Tags: timesfont, nimbus-font

My simple codes are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{times}
\begin{document}

This is for test

\textit{This is for test}

\textbf{This is for test}

\textit{\textbf{This is for test}}
\end{document}
```

If I run, `LaTeX -> dvips -> PS2PDF`, then the font name shows as `Times`

If I run `PDFLaTeX, XeLaTeX`, and `LuaLaTeX` then font names showed as `Nimbus`, I'm aware that it is correct, but is there any possibility to retain the font names "Times" by any chance? Please suggest.....

Comment: Hi, this is the first times that I see the package with the options: `\usepackage[T1,mtbold]{mathtime}`.

Comment: @Sebastiano Sorry, it was old `Y&Y` font package, I'll remove it...For checking purpose, I kept that, missed to remove it...

Comment: Uhm, on my system the font name is `Nimbus` also with `latex+dvips+ps2pdf`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX` on the following file.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times}
\begin{document}
This is for test

\textit{This is for test}

\textbf{This is for test}

\textit{\textbf{This is for test}}
\end{document}
```

In this, don't use `times` it is necessary to use `Times`.
I suspect this question is a duplicate.